# SalesForce - ROR integration No route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines

I am using **salesforce_ar_sync gem** for auto sync when changes made in SalesForce application

I'm new to Rails-Engines, I don't know what URL should be used in SalesForce applications for outbound message

This is result of rake routes

```
salesforce_ar_sync_engine     
/integration               
SalesforceArSync::Engine
```

Routes for SalesforceArSync::Engine:

```
sf_soap_delete  
POST /sf_soap/delete(.:format)                   
salesforce_ar_sync/soap_message#delete

POST /sf_soap/*klass(.:format)   
salesforce_ar_sync/soap_message#sync_object
```

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/sf_soap/*klass")

Comment: kindly share your routes pls.

Comment: I mentioned it in question. all other routes are unrelated.